# How to get the excluded elements when using javascript's filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Javascript's `filter` returns the array with all the elements passing the test.

How how can you easily get all the elements that failed the test without running the test again, but for the converse? How is the best way to do it, even if you have to run the test again.

```
let arr; // this is the array on which the filter will be run [SET ELSEWHERE]
let fn; // The filter function [SET ELSEWHERE]
let goodElements; // This will be the new array of the good elements passing the test
let badElements; // This will be the new array of the elements failing the test

goodElements = arr.filter(fn);

// SO HOW IS badElements set????
```

How is `badElements` set?

Comment: `badElements = arr.filter( el => !goodElements.includes(el) ); `
should do it, or `badElements = arr.filter(el => !fn(el) );`

Comment: The second was the one I initially thought of but did not like as `fn` might not just have `el` as an argument. The first I prefer, but it is running another test again and is obviously longer than the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` in order to split the array into two arrays based on a predicate, like in this example:

```js
const arr = [1, 0, true, false, "", "foo"];
const fn = element => !element;

const [goodElements, badElements] = arr.reduce(
  ([truthies, falsies], cur) =>
    fn(cur) ? [truthies, [...falsies, cur]] : [[...truthies, cur], falsies],
  [[], []]
);

console.log(goodElements, badElements);
```

Comment: ...but wait, what if the fn needs multiple arguments as it can in filter?

Comment: the reduce arguments are the same, in the same order, you can retrieve them and use them if you need to (index and input array)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `filter()`. If you want to partition the data into two arrays, do it yourself.

```
function partition(array, fn) {
  let goodArray = [],
    badArray = [];
  array.forEach(el => {
    if (fn(el)) {
      goodArray.push(el);
    } else {
      badArray.push(el);
    }
  });
  return [goodArray, badArray];
}

let [goodElemements, badElements] = partition(arr, fn);
```

You could also use `reduce()`

```
function partition(array, fn) {
  return array.reduce(acc, el => {
    if (fn(el)) {
      acc[0].push(el);
    } else {
      acc[1].push(el);
    }
  }, [[],[]]);
}

let [goodElemements, badElements] = partition(arr, fn);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I prefer using the array functions rather than forEach.

Comment: You could do it with `reduce()`

Comment: I've added the reduce method.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to do two iterations, you can use a `for` loop and a ternary operator:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let fn = (e) => e % 2 == 0;
let goodElements = [];
let badElements = [];

for(const e of arr) (fn(e) ? goodElements : badElements).push(e);
console.log(goodElements);
console.log(badElements);
```

Otherwise, just invert the condition with the `!` operator:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let fn = (e) => e % 2 == 0;
let goodElements;
let badElements;

goodElements = arr.filter(fn);
badElements = arr.filter(e => !fn(e));
console.log(goodElements);
console.log(badElements);
```

Comment: I considered the "just invert `fn`" approach, but you have to be careful - we don't *know*  what parameters `fn` is expecting, so pass in the rest in case. :wink:

Comment: Nice answer, but I wanted to use the array functions.

Comment: The cleanest and most straightforward solution by far, IMO. Sure, you could do a `for` loop and pass all 3 parameters if need be, but that doesn't change the principle. The only drawback is, it doesn't look like functional programming so you might incur the wrath of the zealots of "modern JavaScript" :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this strictly with `Array.filter` and only one loop, then consider something like this:

UPD: based on [@AlvaroFlañoLarrondo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974822/alvaro-fla%C3%B1o-larrondo) comment, added external condition function to current approach.

```js
// Array of elements
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

// External filter method
const fn = e => e.length > 6;

// Define empty bad array
const bad = [];

// Define good array as result from filter function
const good = words.filter(word => {
  // In filter condition return good values
  if(fn(word)) return word;
  // And skip else values by just pushing them
  // to bad array, without returning
  else bad.push(word);
});

// Results
console.log(good);
console.log(bad);
```

Comment: This is a nice answer considering I initially wanted to use filter. This could be the accepted answer.

Comment: The problem is that this approach needs control over the fun function

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo Well, basically you can put external filter `fn` in `if` condition like `if(fn(word)) return word;`. Or even create a tiny wrapper function around all this stuff, which will return you just `good` and `bad` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible routes:

```js
// in this case, if it's not in `goodElements`, it's a bad 'un
badElements = arr.filter( el => !goodElements.includes(el) );
```

or this:

```js
// we don't **know** if fn needs the optional parameters, so we will
//  simply pass them. If it doesn't need 'em, they'll be ignored.
badElements = arr.filter( (el, idx, arr) => !fn(el, idx, arr) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const fn = (x) => x % 2 === 0

const removeItems = (array, itemsToRemove) => {
    return array.filter(v => {
      return !itemsToRemove.includes(v);
    });
}
  
const goodElements = arr.filter(fn)
console.log(goodElements) // [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ]

const badElements = removeItems(arr, goodElements)
console.log(badElements) // [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]
```